# mysql triggers issues on Update

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I am considering using triggers within my database to keep track of changes of bookings. Each time a booking is added I add a point to in a table that keeps a score in 'tenure'.

When I run this command I am able to change the id before adding the trigger.

```
UPDATE bookit SET prov_id = 32 where book_id=2;
```

after adding the following trigger I get cannot update prov_id and get this error

## 1054 - Unknown column 'bookit.prov_id' in 'where clause'

Trigger:

```
  delimiter //

 CREATE TRIGGER update_tenure_it BEFORE
 
 UPDATE ON bookit FOR EACH ROW

 BEGIN


 if(new.prov_id<>old.prov_id) THEN

 UPDATE provider_score set tenure=(tenure+1) where bookit.prov_id=provider_id;

 END IF;

 END;

 //
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong and where the issue comes from? Should I even consider using triggers for such operation or just code it in PHP? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In triggers, you don't have access directly to the table via `TABLENAME.FIELD`; instead, update triggers give you `old`.* and `new`.* as aliases of the row before and after the update fires, respectively. In this case, the following should work:

```
 delimiter //

 CREATE TRIGGER update_tenure_it BEFORE

 UPDATE ON bookit FOR EACH ROW

 BEGIN


 if(new.prov_id<>old.prov_id) THEN

 UPDATE provider_score set tenure=(tenure+1) where new.prov_id=provider_id;

 END IF;

 END;

 //
```

Answer (score 0):

Your update needs to join in the bookit table to the provider_score table that you're updating. Right now it just has a reference to bookit dangling loose.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am able to succesfully create the trigger, nonehteless even after joining "provider_score.provider_id"

Comment: I can't update in UPDATE bookit SET prov_id = 3 where book_id=2;
and get the same error